# Select only 20 rows of every distinct name

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table in which I have over 1000+ rows, in which there is a column "AnaId", values of this column are repeated many times like name 003912 is repeated 85 times, name 003156 in repeated 70 time, I want to select maximum 20 rows of every distinct AnaID. I have no idea how to do it.

```
SELECT dbo.Analysis.AnaId, Analysis.CasNo, MoleculeId,

    SUM(dbo.AnalysisSummary.Area) as TotalArea

    FROM dbo.Analysis LEFT JOIN dbo.AnalysisSummary

    ON dbo.AnalysisSummary.AnaId = dbo.Analysis.AnaId

    WHERE dbo.Analysis.Sample like '%Oil%'

    GROUP BY dbo.Analysis.AnaId,Analysis.CasNo, MoleculeId ORDER BY 

    TotalArea DESC
```

Comment: Great, now you can look at answers provided by @GordonLinoff and @ChetanKulkami and adapt it. `t` in their answers you can replace with your query.

Comment: It is rude to change questions after you have asked them in a such a way that answers are invalidated.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry I thought It is not necessory to post query also

Answer (score 3):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by name) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 20;
```

With the edits to your question, you can do:

```
with t as (
      <your query here without order by>
     )
    select t.*
    from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by name) as seqnum
          from t
         ) t
    where seqnum <= 20;
```

If you have another table of names, you can also use `cross apply`:

```
select t.*
from names n cross apply
     (select top 20 t.*
      from t
      where t.name = n.name
     ) t;
```

Comment: what is "t" in this query?

Comment: @SyedSibtainAliShah . . . That is for your table.

Comment: SELECT dbo.Analysis.AnaId, Analysis.CasNo, MoleculeId,
 
 SUM(dbo.AnalysisSummary.Area) as TotalArea
 
 FROM dbo.Analysis LEFT JOIN dbo.AnalysisSummary
 
 ON dbo.AnalysisSummary.AnaId = dbo.Analysis.AnaId
 
 WHERE dbo.Analysis.Sample like '%Oil%'

 GROUP BY dbo.Analysis.AnaId,Analysis.CasNo, MoleculeId ORDER BY TotalArea DESC............. This is my query how to filter AnaId top 20 distinct rows

Comment: @SyedSibtainAliShah Add this query in question. We can't guess what you want to do.

Comment: @Rokuto Added query in Question

Comment: @Syed Sibtain Ali Shah - the 't' in that query is called a table alias. It is a name you give to a particular query or field to make your code more readable. It is temporary only and does not change anything at the database level. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you so much it works... And sorry that I didn't post query before.. You're awesome (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Using Rank()

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, rank() over (partition by name order by name) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 20;
```

Using Dense_Rank()

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, Dense_Rank() over (partition by name order by name) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 20;
```

Using Row_Number

```
   select t.*
    from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by name) as seqnum
          from t
         ) t
    where seqnum <= 20;
```

[This will help uunderstand usage of each Special Functions](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/823497/What-is-the-Difference-between-ROW-NUMBER-RANK-and)

Base Code Credits:-@gordon